# PHP str_replace() and preg_replace() not working with HTML

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

When I try to do `str_replace()` or `preg_replace()` within the function, the content does not change.

Content in variable `$sadrzaj`:

```
$sadrzaj = '<p>asdasdasds</p><p><a href="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/image.jpg" itemprop="url" title="some title"><img alt="some alt title" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-243618" src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/image.jpg" width="940" height="529"></a></p>asdasdasd<p>asdasd</p><h3>asdada</h3><p><a href="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/image_02.jpg" itemprop="url" title="some title 02"><img alt="some alt title 02" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-243653" src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/image_02.jpg" width="940" height="529"></a></p><h3>asdasd</h3>';
```

My function `to_je_to()`:

```
function to_je_to($content){
    preg_match_all('/<img (.*?)\/>/', $content, $images);
    //print_r($images);

    if(!is_null($images)){
        foreach($images[1] as $index => $value){
            if(strpos($images[1], 'size-full') !== false){
            //if(preg_match('/alt=""/', $value)){
                $new_img = preg_replace('<img', "<img data-example", $images[0][$index]);
                $content = preg_replace($images[0][$index], $new_img, $content);
            }
        }
    }
    echo $content; // return no difference
}
```

Calling the function `to_je_to($sadrzaj);` - nothing changes.

If there is class with `"size-full"`, find this images and replace their  tag with `<img data-example ...>`.

Even `str_replace()` or `preg_replace()` is not working.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Your `img` tags do not end with `/>` but only `>`, so your regex doesn't capture them.

Comment: ^^^ Here's why we don't parse HTML with regular expressions...

Comment: @miken32 That's right. A DOM parser would seem far more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for feedforward for my drawbacks. I will keep in mind for further programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing wrong is parsing HTML with a regular expression. You should use a proper DOM parser and then you can use XPath queries to isolate your desired elements.

```
<?php
$sadrzaj = '<p>asdasdasds</p><p><a href="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/image.jpg" itemprop="url" title="some title"><img alt="some alt title" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-243618" src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/image.jpg" width="940" height="529"></a></p>asdasdasd<p>asdasd</p><h3>asdada</h3><p><a href="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/image_02.jpg" itemprop="url" title="some title 02"><img alt="some alt title 02" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-243653" src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/image_02.jpg" width="940" height="529"></a></p><h3>asdasd</h3>';

function to_je_to($content) {
    $dom = new DomDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($content, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
    $xp = new DomXpath($dom);
    $nodes = $xp->query("//img[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' size-full ')]");
    foreach ($nodes as $img) {
        $img->setAttribute("data-example", "");
    }
    return $dom->saveHTML();
}
echo to_je_to($sadrzaj);
```

---

And, commenting on your original code: `$images` will never be `null`, it will always be an array. Why loop over `$images[1]` and then replace values based on `$images[0]`? There's no use of the group match `(.*?)` at all so it doesn't need to be there. Neither of the `preg_replace()` calls in the loop use delimiters around the expression to search, so both would have failed with errors. And there is a very big difference between `echo` and `return`.

Comment: @KikiFIstrekNovi this is a better answer than mine. You should accept it instead.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues with your function (in your `preg_match_all`, and `preg_replace`). Also, you need to be more sophisticated in terms of matching the `class` on the `<img>` tag. Overall, you would be better off using the built-in DOMDocument class as the other answer proposes. If you want to keep using regex, this function should fix the issues you had.

```
function to_je_to($content){
    preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+>/', $content, $images);

    if(!is_null($images)){
        foreach($images[0] as $index => $value){
            if(preg_match('/class="[^"]*(?<=["\s])size-full[\s"]/', $value)){
                $new_img = str_replace('<img', '<img data-example', $value);
                $content = preg_replace('/' . preg_quote($value, '/') . '/', $new_img, $content);
            }
        }
    }
    return $content; // return no difference
}
echo to_je_to($sadrzaj);
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/hJT3t)

Comment: Awesome. I really appreciate your help in resolving the problem and your time. Will keep in mind this

Comment: There are errors with this function, I'm seeing double `<` in the output. And I won't go on _too much_ about the many ways this could fail (e.g. `class='not-size-full'` or `alt="this is one size-full too many"`)

Comment: @KikiFIstrekNovi please see my edited answer. I have addressed all the valid points that miken32 has raised.